# Accessing certain information through jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, django-templates

I am working in django templates. I have a form which contains 2 drop downs i.e FROM and DESIGN. After the form ends there is a checkbox which would require the values of the form in javascript.

```
<form method="POST" action="." class="frm-download">
<select id="abc">
        <option>download</option>
        <option>upload</option>
</select>
<select id="action">
        <option>movie</option>
        <option>drama</option>
</select>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="email" value="{{id}}" />Email it?</label>
```

On the front end there can be multiple such structures. My question is **HOW** can I access the specific values of the specific form.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access them on client side, use jquery selector:

```
$('#abc :selected').text()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vJG2z/

Comment: this works fairly well but the situation here is that #abc is a drop down, meaning it is ALWAYS selected. Plus I want the info from #abc only in the case when the checkbox outside the form is selected.

Comment: then only get the select values when the checkbox is changed (.change() ). You should really put more details (like this) into your original question. What is your goal here? What are you doing with the values (where do they go?)?. Is this on form submit or just on checkbox change? The more details you give the easier it is for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

To get the values of your dropdowns use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
var abc_val = $("#abc").val();
var action_val = $("action").val();
```